# Is there a way to create a ColoredCheckbox component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a reusuable material-ui colored checkbox component,
you pass a hex color to the component and it affects the checkbox's color.

I got this so far but i can't think of a way to pass a color to withStyles...

```
const WhiteCheckbox = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#fff',
    '&$checked': {
      color: '#fff',
    },
  },
  checked: {},
})(props => <Checkbox color="default" {...props} />);
```

Thanks in advance if you have any tip to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage props within styles by using a [function for the value](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-rule-value-function?v=v10.0.0#function-values).

Here is a working example of how you could implement this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

const ColoredCheckbox = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    color: ({ color }) => (color ? color : theme.palette.text.secondary),
    "&$checked": {
      color: ({ color }) => (color ? color : theme.palette.text.secondary)
    }
  },
  checked: () => ({})
}))(({ color, ...other }) => <Checkbox color="default" {...other} />);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ColoredCheckbox />
      <ColoredCheckbox color="red" />
      <ColoredCheckbox color="green" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Colored Checkbox]

This defaults the color to `theme.palette.text.secondary` since that is the [default Checkbox behavior](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.1/packages/material-ui/src/Checkbox/Checkbox.js#L16).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i nearly found the solution myself but i forgot to add { color, ...other } to the component ! Works like a charm