# How to pass props to to material-ui styles in a sub-selector

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

Usual apologies if this is asked and answered...

I've got a stylesheet:

```
const styles = createStyles({
    root: {background: 'blue', color: 'red'},
    highlightedWrapper: {
        '& $root': {
           background: 'green',
           color: 'black'
        }
    }
})
```

...which I invoke like this:

`const useStyles = makeStyles(kanbanStyles);`

...and then reference in my component like this:

`const classes = useStyles()`

So far, so good. What I'd like to be able to do is pass props into `useStyles()`, which I'd then reference in the stylesheet. So this works:

```
const classes = useStyles({color: 'yellow'})

const styles = createStyles({
    root: (props) => { return {background: 'blue', color: props.color}},
    highlightedWrapper: {
        '& $root': {
           background: 'green',
           color: 'black'
        }
    }
})
```

...but I cannot figure out how to invoke the function inside the sub-selector. Like, this doesn't work for me:

```
const styles = createStyles({
    root: {background: 'blue', color: props.color},
    highlightedWrapper: {
        '& $root': {
           background: 'green',
           color: (props) => props.color
        }
    }
})
```

I've tried various permutations of the above syntax, putting it right after `hightlightedWrapper:`, and right after `'& $root':`, but nothing has worked.

Help?

Thanks!!

Comment: Use the same syntax in `root` as what you have in `highlightedWrapper` (`color: (props) => props.color`) and it should be fine.

Comment: A couple working examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397369/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-coloredcheckbox-component/58397932#58397932 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008320/using-props-to-set-hover-background-color/55010155#55010155.

Comment: @RyanCogswell unless I'm missing something (which could well be the case), I've already tried that syntax. See my example above. As I mention below, I'm using Typescript, which means I have to use `createStyles`, and I wonder if that's somehow throwing things off somehow?

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Comment: yeah...yeah, good idea. Gimme a bit.

Comment: Huh. This works.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-ugqwp

Color me befuddled. Obviously something else is afoot.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Wait! I take it back! My sandbox was wrong, and masked the issue. Here's an updated sandbox that shows the issue. I would expect "Name Two" to be red, and then fall back to blue, but it shows as green.

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-dan-1o387

Comment: Works fine after fixing the rule syntax to `"& $name"` (https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-kapitsa-2bl0k). Without the space you were matching elements that have both the `wrapper` and `name` classes rather than matching `name` descendants of `wrapper`.

Comment: wait...wait... I just noticed this:
```name: {color: props => "green"}```

If I change that to `name: {color: "green"}`, then it breaks. So it looks like if you're going to use a function for CSS rule, that you have to use a function every other place you reference that rule, even if the other places don't have dynamic values?

Comment: That aspect is a known bug that is unlikely to be fixed: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13672#issuecomment-541118923

Comment: Well, allow me to just: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props to @RyanCogswell for the answer, but the issue is that if you're going to use a function for a style, in order to handle dynamic props, you *must* use a function everywhere that style is referenced. So this will break:

```
  wrapper: {
    '& $name': {
      color: (props) => (props.color ? props.color : 'blue')
    }
  },
  name: {
    color: 'green'
  }
```

...but this will work:

```
  wrapper: {
    '& $name': {
      color: (props) => (props.color ? props.color : 'blue')
    }
  },
  name: {
    color: (props) => 'green'
  }
```

Notice the `(props) => 'green'`.

This is a bug that may not get resolved anytime soon:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13672#issuecomment-541118923