# How do I override checkbox color (box and font) in disabled state in material ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In Material UI v4.9.12 I can create a custom checkbox with a (fixed) different color:

```
const GreenCheckbox = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: green[400],
    '&$checked': {
        color: green[600],
    },
  },
  checked: {},
})((props) => {
    return <Checkbox {...props} />
  }
)
```

But this doesn't change the font color and only sets the color when the checkbox isn't disabled.

How can I do both? What do I have to override?

So far I only managed to override the icon color with inline styling:

`<GreenCheckbox style={{color: green[600]}} onChange={cb} checked={checked} disabled/>`

Comment: From your code snippet, you want `green` when `unchecked, and `darker green` when `checked`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. But my problem is with the disabled state. It overrides the 'normal' styling. So I'd like to know what (and how) I have to override to also change the styling for a disabled checkbox

Comment: @Zapnuk What do you mean by "this doesn't change the font color"? The font color is the only thing being impacted by your styles. If you mean the color of the check, that is actually the background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [default styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui/src/Checkbox/Checkbox.js#L53) for the `disabled` state with the exact same approach you used for the `checked` state:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import green from "@material-ui/core/colors/green";

const GreenCheckbox = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: green[400],
    "&$checked": {
      color: green[600]
    },
    "&$disabled": {
      color: green[200]
    }
  },
  checked: {},
  disabled: {}
})(Checkbox);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GreenCheckbox />
      <GreenCheckbox disabled />
      <GreenCheckbox checked disabled />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Colored Checkbox]

Related answers:

- [Change the tick color in MuiCheckbox material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970631/change-the-tick-color-in-muicheckbox-material-ui/57982412#57982412)
- [Is there a way to create a ColoredCheckbox component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397369/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-coloredcheckbox-component/58397932#58397932)

Comment: Thanks, What I ment with the font color was the color of the overarching FormControlLabel. I'm my specific usecase I'd like the checkbox + label have the same color.
My mistake, I worded the question very poorly.